# What are the pros and cons of Apple Developer Connection

Tags: development

My father thinks I should subscribe to the equivalent of a journal for software development and such.  I suppose for me, that's Apple Developer Connection amongst a bunch of magazines etc.  What are the benefits of ADC? is it worth the money?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADC is reasonable value if that's what you need... but it isn't anything like a journal.  It's more an update service, and gives you access to software previews so you can have your apps ready when OS updates and the like actually ship, and tech support from Apple when you have issues that Stack Overflow can't sort out.  So, if you're doing commercial development or IT support for a large Mac shop, it's useful.  But it's not like a magazine or academic journal, not even slightly.

Comment: A long time ago there was a magazine involved called "develop", which eventually merged with MacTutor/MacTech.  You can get it on the MacTech back issue CD or DVD, but it's of historical interest only now.